# Package Manager Error: setting up language-selector-common

Tags: 10.10, package-management, dpkg

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and I wanted to install python-setuptools package. So I did a

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

In the command line and It downloaded the package and went on to the configuration step.
However, Package Manager gave some error messages in the console while python-setuptools were installing, which was this.

```
Selecting previously deselected package python-setuptools.
(Reading database ... 146674 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python-setuptools (from .../python-setuptools_0.6.14-3ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Setting up language-selector-common (0.6.7) ...
dpkg: error processing language-selector-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector:
 language-selector depends on language-selector-common (= 0.6.7); however:
  Package language-selector-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing language-selector (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-setuptools (0.6.14-3ubuntu1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Processing triggers for python-central ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 language-selector-common
 language-selector
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

According to the output, I figured that python-setuptools was correctly installed. But what are the other errors it reporting? Any insight will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: basically your language-selector-common package was not configured. You may try `dpkg-reconfigure language-selector-common` or `dpkg-reconfigure language-selector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/language-selector/+bug/766534).

**Update:** The bug status is now "Fix Released", so you should expect a fix with the next update to `lanugage-selector`.